# Invalid HTTP Response

Tags: java, php, http, wamp, ioexception

I am  trying to send request to PHP page from Java.

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$result = signin();
if($result == "1"){
    echo "1";
}else{
    echo "0";
}

function signin(){
    global $uname;
    global $pass;
    global $db;

    $connect = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user where uname=? and pass=?");
    $connect->execute(array($uname,$pass));
    $result = $connect->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $row){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
?>
```

My Java Method :

```
public int checkPass(){
        try{
            // open a connection to the site
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.35/userControls/singin.php");
            URLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            ((HttpURLConnection) con).setRequestMethod("POST");
            // activate the output
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            //con.setDoInput(true);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
            ps.print(URLEncoder.encode("?uname","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(uname, "UTF-8"));
            ps.print(URLEncoder.encode("&pass=","UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "utf-8"));

            ps.close();
            BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = cin.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(":::::::Worked:::::::::   " + line);
            }
           }/* catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }*/ catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Eror:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        return 1;
    }
```

But when I run this, the error: (INVALID HTTP RESPONSE)

> java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1555)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>       at CapitalizeServer$Capitalizer.checkPass(CapitalizeServer.java:171)
>       at CapitalizeServer$Capitalizer.run(CapitalizeServer.java:64)

The line 171 of CapitalizeServer.java is :

```
BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

I am using WAMP Server-2.4.9

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the Java running from the same machine (or from the same network)?

Comment: It's running on the same machine

Comment: `URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.35/userControls/singin.php");`  - Possible typo here - `signin.php` or `signin.php`?

Comment: What is the actual HTTP response that your PHP code is providing?  For example, what do you see when you use `curl` to send a `POST` to your PHP code?

Comment: I don't know about curl, if you asking the answer that should come, it should be "1" or "0", but the code is not running.